# fmap replace literals in parse trees

Tags: haskell

I want to change all literals.

```hs
data Expressions a = ListExpression String[Expressions a]
| BinaryExpression String (Expressions a) (Expressions a)
| UnaryExpression String(Expressions a)
| Variables Variable
| Literals a
deriving Eq
```

Now i want to have all `Literals` changed to `b`, if the literals in `c` equals `b`.
So example:

```hs
changeData 20 30 (Literals 100) = (Literals 100)
changeData 20 30 (Literals 20) = (Literals 30)
```

The expression itself should not be changed.

```hs
changeData :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Expressions a -> Expressions a
changeData a b c
```

I dont understand how to access it.
I thought something like this:

```hs
 fmap (Literals b == Literals a) (\x -> if x == True = a else b)
```

I thought like: Literals b == Literals a for each Expression.
If true, then change to a, otherwise to b.

But like I wrote it down, its not working and I cant figure my mistake out.

Am im fundamentally missunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your `Functor` instance is making up data constructors, rather than using the ones that were actually defined.

```
instance Functor Expressions where
     fmap f (Literals a) = Literals (f a)
     fmap f (Variables a) = Variables a
     fmap f (UnaryExpression a b) = UnaryExpression a (fmap f b)
     fmap f (BinaryExpression a b c) = BinaryExpression a (fmap f b) (fmap f c) 
     fmap f (ListExpression a b) = ListExpression a (fmap (fmap f) b)
```

Next, all you need is a function that checks if its argument is equal to `a`: if it is, return `b`; otherwise return the argument.

```
changeData a b c = fmap (\x -> if x == a then b else x) c
```

The definition of `fmap` already handles each of the data constructors for `Expression`; the function only needs to worry about the value extracted from a `Literals` value. (That is, `f` is only ever applied to a value in a `Literals` value; otherwise, it is just `fmap`ped recursively until it reaches a `Literals`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can let Haskell derive the instance for the [**`Functor`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) with the [**`DeriveFunctor`** GHC extension](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/derive-functor):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Expressions a
  = ListExpression String [Expressions a]
  | BinaryExpression String (Expressions a) (Expressions a)
  | UnaryExpression String (Expressions a)
  | Variables Variable
  | Literals a
  deriving (Eq, Functor)
```

GHC will generate a `Functor` instance where it maps items of type `a` to type `b` by calling the functor function on these, and it will recurse on expressions with an `a` to map the `a` items wrapped in these subexpressions.

Then you can use `fmap` for `changeData` as [@chepner says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70329283/67579) with:

```
changeData :: Eq a => a -> a -> Expressions a -> Expressions a
changeData a b = fmap (\x -> x == a then b else x)
```